# How to test API from a ROS1 package that works with another ROS2 package?

Tags: api, ros, ros2

I have found one ROS1 git repo/package. But it was tested with confirmed ROS Version : ROS Melodic Morenia and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  So it can be build with `catkin_build`. Using the following commands

```
$ cd ~/
$ mkdir --parents catkin_ws/src
$ cd catkin_ws
$ catkin init
$ catkin build
```

A reference site about vcstool that builds packages after installing dependent packages and overlays your workspace on the installation environment

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/ros1-package.git
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python-vcstool python-rosdep python-catkin-tools
$ git clone https://github.com/strv/vcstool-utils.git
$ rosdep install --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src -r -y
$ ./vcstool-utils/import_all.sh -s .rosinstall ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin build
$ source ../devel/setup.bash
```

Then I have my own repo/package but it uses ROS2. I would like to try and test the existing API of the first ROS1 git repo/package to see if its works together with my own ROS2 package. Would appreciate  a help how can proceed and how can test/try the API of the first ROS1 package with my own ROS2 package. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROS 1 to ROS 2 bridge: https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge